# Android app resets after some idle time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reset

I've recently created my first android app. It's a really simple app that has two counters to keep scores for two teams in an IRL card game. Anyway, if the user chooses to visit other apps while having the app open like for ex. check whatsapp and have the app running in the background, it works fine, most of the time... If the user is away from the app for a longer time the app tends to reset to it's default state, meaning the score counters are both reset to 0 which is very frustrating. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Like saving the app's state in memory until the user returns or something like that? The app counters are basic Textview objects. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop your process from being terminated. Save your data in a database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other sort of file, if you want that data to survive even after your process has been terminated.

Comment: You can prevent a process from being terminated: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground but this is probably not what this user want.

Comment: @01BTC10: That merely increases the likelihood that the process will stick around. It is not a guarantee, and there are ways that the process can still be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The state can be saved/recovered via the savedInstanceState variable.

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

When the user use another apps then the onPause(), onStop() event get called. After some time the OS free the memory and call onDestroy(). This is your last chance to save any state.

Comment: This state will only last for a short while (~30 minutes or so). That may or may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putInt("int", 1); 
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("int");
}
```

or use library: [IcePick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick)

Comment: Thanks. How do I use this exactly? Can I just put this into my code? I'm sorry I am new to this and the code looks unfamiliar to me so not really sure what to make of it.

Comment: yes, you can use but set your own variables:
here   savedInstanceState.putInt("int", 1); 
and here
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("int");